# Rails SQL injection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, sql-injection

In Rails, when I want to find by a user given value and avoid SQL injection (escape apostrophes and the like) I can do something like this:

```
Post.all(:conditions => ['title = ?', params[:title]])
```

I know that an unsafe way of doing this (possible SQL injection) is this:

```
Post.all(:conditions => "title = #{params[:title]}")
```

My question is, does the following method prevent SQL injection or not?

```
Post.all(:conditions => {:title => params[:title]})
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, it does. Only the second one is dangerous.

Comment: Thank you for your direct response.

Answer (score 8):

One [good reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection) from the RoR Guides.

Answer (score 5):

+1 @fphilipe and @yuval Check this 5 min video from [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/25-sql-injection) and this one from [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection)

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this already but it doesn't cover my question (pertaining to the last find)