# Changing Rails Query to Pure SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm looking to move the following code away from ActiveRecord to pure SQL for a performance increase.  What would be the best way to write this query in pure SQL (MySQL DB)?

```
User.count(:conditions => ["email = ?",params[:email]]) > 0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analogously to [find_by_sql](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class) you can use [count_by_sql](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/count_by_sql/class):

```
User.count_by_sql(["SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users u WHERE u.email = ?", params[:email]]) > 0
```

Remember also to use the syntax `["... ? ...", var]` here to protect against [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962263/rails-sql-injection).

However, I doubt that you can achieve a significant performance improvement by that. Test it. If it's not faster, stay with the ActiveRecord version or try to find a more nifty solution to your problem.

Edit:

If you just want to test whether an given email is already contained in the table you could also test the performance of `User.find_by_email(params[:email]).present?`

Comment: +1 - @Spashlin - poor performance probably means your User.Email column needs an index.

Comment: Alternately, you could use `User.exists?(:email => params[:email])` if you're just looking to see if the user is already present. This takes care of escaping automatically.