# Activerecord query where array include an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to create a query to show every content of a section in my CMS.

The relation is one to many, one content has many sections.

Now I create a section controller and in the show method i receive the params[:id] of a section.

I must select all the contents where the content.section_ids array include my params[:id]

I know how to create the inverse query (where ID in array), but I cannot find a solution for this.

My query is:

```
@contents = Content.published.recent.where("#{params[:id]} IN (?)", ...)
```

**Update**

This is the relation.

I must select all the contents where the section is == to the section ID passed in my params.

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :sections, as: :sectionable
end

class Section< ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sectionable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Comment: it sounds like you've created a one-to-many relationship by making a Content have a `section_ids` field that's some kind of array or serialized array, rather than using a `content_id` foreign key on the sections table? Clearer information about the structure of your database is needed to adequately answer the question. What db are you even using?

Answer (score 2):

```
@contents = Content.published.recent.where(:id => params[:id])
```

Don't put params into where clause like `("id in (#{params[:id])")` as it's vulnerable for sql injections. More details are here [Rails SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962263/rails-sql-injection)