# Rails 4 - Prevent SQL injection using LIKE operator in SQL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sql-injection, parameters, sql-like

I'd like to use the following query for my Rails 4 application but am concerned about SQL injection attacks:

```
@persons = People.where("persons.name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%")
```

Can somebody show me the safe way to write the above statement?  I've tried the following but am not sure if it is SQL-injection-proof:

```
search = "%" + params[:search] + "%"
@persons = People.where("persons.name LIKE ?", search)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your examples are fine, as zishe said.

Whenever you use question marks to a method and pass another parameters as the search query, it sanitizes your query string.

It is dangerous when you manually do string concatenations to create your query, for example:

```
Project.where("name = '#{params[:name]}'")
```

[Click here for more information](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection)

Comment: Thanks, @Migore!  I appreciate the additional resource as well as the explanation as to why my examples are SQL injection-proof!

Answer (score 9):

Both your statements will be safe. Also you can write it like this:

```
@persons = People.where("persons.name LIKE concat('%', ?, '%')", params[:search])
```

[Simlilar qestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962263/rails-sql-injection)

Comment: No, the pattern must be a string. You don't have the SQL string in quotes. But you must not put the placeholder inside a SQL string. This would work: `"persons.name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')"`

Comment: @zishe - thanks for answering my question as well as providing a more concise piece of code.  I'm accepting Migore's response since he provided some additional information as to why my examples were not vulnerable to SQL injection.  Thanks!